Showing a window resize grip
A simple window created with 'F'⎕WC'Form' can be resized by the user but there is no resize grip in the lower right corner. If we add a status bar with 'F.SB'⎕WC'StatusBar', however, the grip is shown. To me it's not clear why the grip is only shown when the window has a statusbar. Is there a way to add a grip to any window without adding a status bar? I use Dyalog APL 16.0 Classic.


Technical answer: No.
Practically, you can fake it to the point where it is almost there, and might in fact be good enough:

Here's how I achieved this:

'F'⎕WC'Form'('Coord' 'Pixel')('BCol' ¯6)
'B'⎕WC'Bitmap'('File' 'Grip.png')
'F.S'⎕WC'Static'(F.Size-11 11)(11 11)('Attach' 'Bottom' 'Right' 'Bottom' 'Right')('BCol' F.BCol)('Border'0)('Picture' 'B')

This places a fake grip (I screenshot it from a real one) in the bottom right corner.
Downsides of this approach:

The real grip extends the active diagonal resizing area from being just the form border to a small square area, while this fake gripper doesn't do that.

The grip might interfere with other controls that are placed in the extreme bottom right corner of the Form

You have to explicitly set the form's BCol so it can be copied by the Static and my bitmap doesn't look so nice on colours that are far from white or light grey

If Microsoft changes the look of the grip, you'll have to update the bitmap


